# Rails Active record consuming too much memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, memory-leaks, rails-activerecord

I have been using rails 4.2.8 and ruby 2.6.6

In my application we have huge database(postGresql).

In report section when I am trying to generate reports(much more complex quesries, many models used), I see total allocated memory is huge.

I am using worker to generate report. Here is the main part of the memory profiler gem's generate report:

```
Total allocated: 335531877 bytes (4301278 objects)
Total retained:  2100410 bytes (21442 objects)

allocated memory by gem
-----------------------------------
263364691  activerecord-4.2.8
```

As you can see total memory used: 335MB where active record consumed 263MB. It is my local report. In production server consumed memory almost 700MB.

Is it normal scenario?  Sometimes I am getting `Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)` in production server.

Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: "Is it normal scenario?" we have no idea what you are doing or what you are trying to do. Chances are this could be optimized a bit, chances are you are loading a lot of full or partial model objects (which probably aren't required for reporting), chances are you could off load more work to the database or pre-calculate some portion of this data but unfortunately it is currently impossible to tell based solely on what was provided here.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky

Actually I have used batch queries with batch size 300. Also I have select only required fields in the queries. I can not pre-calculate data because we have so many filters and combinations. User can choose many combinations of filters to generate reports.
My query is: Is it normal active record taking most of the memory(almost 80%) of the total memory used in the worker?

Comment: Do you actually need the active record objects or would raw query table data suffice for your reports? There is a lot of overhead in instantiating AR objects